# Inheriting from AppCompat Toolbar changes Toolbar icon margin

Tags: android, android-toolbar

In my project I'm extending `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` to add some extra functionality to the class. However, when I implement this class in my layout file it changes the margin (or padding, not sure...) of the icons displayed on the Toolbar.

**Default android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar result:**

[image: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar]

**Custom Toolbar class result:**

[image: Custom Toolbar]

My custom Toolbar class has no extra code yet, it simply implements the required constructors, so I'm not manipulating the margin myself.

Here's the custom Toolbar class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.AttributeSet;


public class ThemedToolbar extends Toolbar {

    public ThemedToolbar(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public ThemedToolbar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public ThemedToolbar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
}
```

And here's the Toolbar layout file I'm including in all my activities:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="?actionBarSize">

    <com.endare.ui.theme.view.ThemedToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_control"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_content_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

So basically, all I did in the layout file to see the different results is switching `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` with `<com.endare.ui.theme.view.ThemedToolbar`.

How can I prevent my custom Toolbar implementation of changing the margin of the icons?

Answer (score 5):

You have to put `R.attr.toolbarStyle` as the `defStyleAttr` parameter in the second constructor.